# When rendering with GPU Compute, GPU doesn't seem to work that much harder

Tags: gpu

For some reason, my rx 470 graphics card which is great for gaming and so on, cannot render faster than my intel i5 processor. Why is this? Wouldn't GPU Compute make things run faster. And, if that wasn't enough. My task manager indicates that the GPU's percentage of usage does not go up beyond 2-3% when rendering. I want more of my gpu to be used. Is there any way I can do this?

For example, when rendering this snowman, my cpu took less than one second, while my gpu took a little less than three seconds.[image: Rendered with GPU Compute]. And here is the same render done with the cpu. Notice the time difference. [image: CPU only takes .26 seconds].

I am a little annoyed, since I paid a lot for my graphics card, hoping to do animations. But, for some reason, it just isn't cutting it.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information to answer this question. Which rendering engine are you using? If cycles, what tile sizes are you using? Some screenshots of your render settings would be helpful too.

Comment: Did you adjust the size of the render tiles to make better use of the GPU? CPU requires small tile sizes (16 or 32 are a good starting value to test,) on GPU you should use larger tiles (around 256)

Comment: uh, no. I thought that was automatically done. How do I change it?

Comment: Under performance in the render tab of the properties panel.

Comment: Okay, I finally found out how to increase the tile size, but the GPU Compute still isn't really that much faster than my i5. I have my settings set to GPU acceleration with OpenCL, and am wondering if I can get anything more out of my gpu. And, the usage is still unrealistically low.

Comment: I don't know blender stack overflow very well. Is there a way I can post another picture here?

Comment: Just click the edit button at the bottom left of your question

Comment: thx. Here are my settings

Comment: "*Wouldn't GPU Compute make things run faster*" No, not necessarily. If your GPU is low end or slower than your CPU it will actually be slower. Also GPU task managers with "core load graphs" aren't really that reliable source of info

Comment: First, you shouldn't put text in images - screenreaders can't read the text in an image, crawlers like Googlebot can't index text in images (just write what you would have put in your image, as text below the image). Second, freehand squiggles and freehand text make your images look *really sloppy* - you probably got downvotes just because of that.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos In this case GPU compute should make things run faster. If the benchmarks are any indication, his card should be much quicker than his CPU.

Comment: Is this a laptop?
You might have a performance throttling issue due to how the power usage is handled if it is.

Comment: No, it is a desktop built by myself. Also, sorry for the inconvient sloppiness in the screenshot, but I did my best to highlight what was going on.

Comment: Try rendering a higher resolution and see if that makes a difference. Just to make sure, you are using 256x256 tile size for GPU right?

Comment: I did. Now the difference between the cpu time and gpu time is 24 and 26 seconds respectively. I did use 256 by 256 tiling

Comment: Also, the memory on the rx 470 is only 4gb whereas my computer's onboard memory is 8 gigs. Could that be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that using auto tiling size from an addon made my day. Apparently, there are issues with opencl and amd optimization, the fault being AMD's. But, when I installed the addon, the tile size ended up making a huge difference. Before it was installed, I changed the tile size to 256 but for some reason did not get the same results. I hope this is okay if I figured it out on my own.

Comment: Answering your own question is totally fine, and is also much better than solving the question but not telling anyone. Glad to hear you got things all sorted out.

Comment: For example people like me :-P... Just thought about (I knew that add on but for some reason in my 2.8 it was deactivated by default and with you post I came me in mind, to enable it...